# Converting datatype in Object from int to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, object

I have following 2 arrays of object. I want to convert the array from 1st format to 2nd format, i.e, data values stored from int to string, but unable to find a convinient way. Can someone help? [image]

Please, help out with a way to do so easily by Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> The [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var test = [{
  id: 0,
  title: 0
}, {
  id: 1,
  title: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 2
}, {
  id: 3,
  title: 3
}];
var newArray = test.map(function(item) {
  return {
    id: item.id.toString(),
    title: item.title.toString()
  };
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for example:

```
tootSetArray.map(function(item){
  return {
    id: '' + item.id,
    title: '' + item.title
  };
});
```

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.